# Subquery with IN clause

Tags: sql-server, pgadmin-3

I have a table named “groups” whose projects have been funded as shown

[image]

I have written a query giving the names of all groups that were funded in both 2014 and 2018 using the INTERSECT clause as follows

```
SELECT group.NAME
FROM group
WHERE group.YEAR = 2014
EXCEPT
SELECT group.NAME
FROM group
WHERE group.YEAR = 2018
```

I want to write this same query using a sub-request with the IN clause but I am unable to write the condition. This is what I have

```
SELECT group.NAME
FROM group
WHERE group.YEAR IN (SELECT group.YEAR
FROM group WHERE group.YEAR = 2014 AND group.YEAR = 2018)
```

Comment: pgAdmin is a tool for (only) Postgres  which is a completely different database product than SQL Server - which one are you really using? Postgres or SQL Server?

Comment: In your query, for which you say you use INTERSECT, I only see `EXCEPT`. Try to correct that!.  The output of the current query is an empty result....

Comment: How can there possibly be any row in `group` where `year` = 2014 and `year` also = 2018?

Answer (score 1):

This gives the result:

> **Name**
>
> Coace
>
> Fodec

query:

```
SELECT Name
FROM GROUPS
WHERE [year] in (2014,2018)
group by Name
having count(*)>=2
```

Count if the group (or groups, your query is unclear about that!) are in 2 or more years.

Comment: Should probably switch it to a `count(distinct [year]) >= 2` to be more general (in case multiple rows with the same group and year are possible).

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Comment: @scott  I hope there's no possibility to store the year twice in this simple table, but you are right.   Also Amabo should not use reserverd words (YEAR, GROUP) for table and/or fieldnames.....

Comment: @Luuk Certainly not in this simple table. But if this was just an example extracted from a larger table, where perhaps a group can be partially funded from multiple sources, or multiple times throughout the year or something like that, then I could see multiple rows.

Comment: `SELECT Name 
FROM GROUPS
WHERE [year] in (2014,2018)
group by Name,rollup([year])
having count(*)>=2` …. Because I do not like DISTINCT.(personal opinion)... 

Comment: I'm not a big fan of `DISTINCT` either, but that's a lot more self-documenting than adding `rollup` to the `group by` (also personal opinion).

Comment: You  are absolutely right!